# How to handle and deploy configuration properties per environment?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a configuration, for example, hostname of external server to store files (like images and PDFs), stored in settings files. These settings are stored in a class library called CommonSettings. The value of this path may change depending the environment the application is deployed. This is:

- For local environment, the value is `"localhost"`
- For QA environment, the value is `"qa-external-files"`
- For prod environment, the value is `"prod-external-files"`

Then I have to access in code to such settings but I need to decouple the value of the settings per environment from the code. For example, I would want to achieve something like this (tests in Console Application using C#):

```
using CommonSettings;

String externalServerHostName = CommonSettings.Properties.Setting.Default.ExternalServerHostName;
Console.Write(externalServerHostName);
//prints localhost when I execute this from my machine
//prints qa-external-files when I execute this from the qa environment
```

In Java I can handle this scenario by creating folder structure and have a folder per environment, then each folder containing the related settings inside a file (properties file) and using an automated build tool (maven) to generate the library containing only the properties files according to the environment I want/need.

Can I have a similar approach using .net? Or should I use a build tool that handles this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to store your configuration settings in an app.config file instead of a class library? If so, you can apply transformations to the app.config depending on which environment you are in. You are right that the transformation should probably be handled during build and not during runtime.

If you have an ASP.Net application, web.config transforms are much easier:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you are using WPF or something not ASP, it is a bit more work to do transforms on app.config. Luckily, there is an VSIX file for Visual Studio that will help with this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Comment: I'll be using these configurations in a WCF project. Usually, I have these settings stored in a third party library (call it jar in Java world, DLL in .net world, etc.) because they should be accessible from the service (business logic) layer rather than the presentation layer. The presentation layer may vary from a Web application and a backend application. That's why I need to decouple the settings.